# record show more than 5 times in query

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I try to execute the query, but it shows me data more than 5 times. Here is the query which I used

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[dddddd]
    @userid int
as
    SELECT DocumentInfo.DocID as DocumentID,
        dbo.DocumentInfo.DocName as DocumentName,
        dbo.DocumentInfo.Uploadfile as FileUploaded,
        dbo.DocType.DocType as Document,
        dbo.Department.DepType as Department,
        dbo.ApproveType.ApproveType AS ApproveID
    FROM dbo.DocumentInfo
      inner JOIN dbo.DocType ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DocTypeID=dbo.DocType.DocTypeID
      inner JOIN dbo.Department ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DepID=dbo.Department.DepID
      LEFT JOIN dbo.ApproveType ON dbo.ApproveType.approveid=dbo.Department.DepID  
      LEFT OUTER JOIN Approval a ON a.DocID = a.DocID
      JOIN ApproveType at ON at.ApproveID = ISNULL(a.Approveid, 3)  
    where UserID=@userid
```

see this result..

```
DocumentID  DocumentName    FileUploaded    Document    Department  ApproveID
    8   SDASDASD    dsfsdf.docx MSWord  Human Resource  NULL
    8   SDASDASD    dsfsdf.docx MSWord  Human Resource  NULL
     8  SDASDASD    dsfsdf.docx MSWord  Human Resource  NULL
     8  SDASDASD    dsfsdf.docx MSWord  Human Resource  NULL
   8    SDASDASD    dsfsdf.docx MSWord  Human Resource  NULL
    8   SDASDASD    dsfsdf.docx MSWord  Human Resource  NULL

  9 dr reprt n analysis HR.docx MSWord  Human Resource  NULL
  9 dr reprt n analysis HR.docx MSWord  Human Resource  NULL
   9    dr reprt n analysis HR.docx MSWord  Human Resource  NULLL
 9  dr reprt n analysis HR.docx MSWord  Human Resource  NULL
 9  dr reprt n analysis HR.docx MSWord  Human Resource  NULL
  10    hr report   HR.docx MSWord  Human Resource  NULL
 10 hr report   HR.docx MSWord  Human Resource  NULL
 10 hr report   HR.docx MSWord  Human Resource  NULL
 10 hr report   HR.docx MSWord  Human Resource  NULL
```

where is the mistake?

Comment: What's magical about "5 times"?  I'm guessing you need some extra join conditions to filter out unrelated combinations.

Comment: i mean record which is save in table ...when i create this sp then record shows me more than 5 timess..

Comment: where as i insert record only 1 time but it show me 1 record in 5 times @DStanley

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing, but this line does not look right:

```
LEFT JOIN dbo.ApproveType ON dbo.ApproveType.approveid=dbo.Department.DepID
```

Are `approveid` and `DepID` really the same thing?

Comment: when i try this ...LEFT JOIN dbo.ApproveType ON dbo.ApproveType.approveid=dbo.DocumentInfo.ApproveID   it is always show me more than 5 times records

Answer (score 1):

You apparently have a 1:N relationship in one of your joins that you are not properly joining.  One way to solve this is to include more columns and see which ones have different values that do not apply to your query.

For example (complete guess):

```
LEFT JOIN dbo.ApproveType ON dbo.ApproveType.approveid=dbo.Department.DepID
```

Will this return ALL approvals for a particular department?  Do you need to filter down for just approvals for the specified documents?

Answer (score 1):

Your joins are bringing back multiple rows...can't provide an exact answer, but to find the join causing it:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.DocumentInfo
  inner JOIN dbo.DocType ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DocTypeID=dbo.DocType.DocTypeID
  inner JOIN dbo.Department ON dbo.DocumentInfo.DepID=dbo.Department.DepID
  LEFT JOIN dbo.ApproveType ON dbo.ApproveType.approveid=dbo.Department.DepID  
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Approval a ON a.DocID = a.DocID
  JOIN ApproveType at ON at.ApproveID = ISNULL(a.Approveid, 3)  
where documentid = 8
```

This will bring back the 5 records you are having issues with and all columns for document 8.  Take a look through each value and verify these are duplicate lines.  If you find a column has different values for the 5 rows, then you have the table that is causing the extra rows.  Revisit the join and add new logic to limit it to one row not 5.

Alternative to this is to comment out each table one at a time and re-run.  If you get the same number of rows, then that table is good...if you comment out a table and get 1 row, then you have found which table is causing the extra rows and you'll need new logic in your join to get this down to one row.

Comment: i done this and check every line but in every line it always show me same records

Comment: how many rows does select * from dbo.documentInfo where documentid = 8 return?

Comment: 29 rows but here i post less record but in many database it show me 29 records.

Comment: So you have 29 records in the documentinfo table that match documentID 8?   Doesn't it make sense that your query would return 5+ rows when there is 29 of them in your primary table?  I'm starting to think your query is fine, it's dirty data causing your issue.

Comment: noo...there is only one 1 record in document info table but it shows me 29 records...

Comment: k, now I'm really confused...I asked how many rows select * from dbo.documentInfo where documentid = 8  and you said 29 rows.  A select * like that returns all rows from that table matching id 8 and nothing else...if there is only 1 record in documentinfo table, how is a select * from that table returning 29 rows?  It's one or the other, not both.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I do to troubleshoot these problems is find the first shared ID for the join and check that.  So if you got back 5 records that all had dbo.DocumentInfo.DocTypeID = 7 then do a select against dbo.DocType where DocTypeID=7.  Do you get 5 answers.  If not, go to the next join, select data from Department where DepartmentID=(whatever is repeating) until you find the join that is duplicating the data.  Then figure out how the tables are joined to get a 1-1 join rather than 1 - M.